# electric gate motor

Tags: electric-motor

I have a question about an electric gate motor I am installing. I purchased a motor rated for up to 650kg(for a level area), but it will operate on a slope which drops by 400mm over the 5 metre opening which the gate will span.  The gate weighs approx. 250kg but I am concerned that the motor will lose traction or the clutch will fail and crush a child as it rolls down the slope, is this a possibility?Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: A picture or diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Can you install the gate so that if the clutch fails the gate will roll open?

Comment: The type or model of the gate would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is why garage door openers have pass transmitters that stop and reverse the door to prevent such an accident.

Does your gate opener have any safety features to prevent this? If not then maybe you should look for one that has these safety features.

Good luck!